# Override product prices in custom query

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I know this is not a woocommerce related websites, I tried the official forum, but no reply in 3 days. I spent a day or more with this, so I hope you can help.

I created a custom wp_query for the products. These products has a custom field (custom_price). I would like to override the prices in the query with the values of the custom fields.

I saw questions here about this, but I'm very new in php/wordpress. I really appreciate your help.

My query:

```
<?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>
        <?php
            if(is_front_page()){
                $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'posts_per_page' => 6,
                'meta_key' => '_featured',
                'meta_value' => 'yes'

                );
                $query = new WP_Query( $args );
                if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                        $query->the_post();
                        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
                    }
                }
                wp_reset_query();
            }
        ?>
        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the price that is displayed, then you can implement the filters `woocommerce_price_html`, `woocommerce_sale_price_html`, `woocommerce_cart_item_price_html`. This will result in the displayed price being whatever you would like, however the actual price in the cart used for calculating tax, shipping, totals, etc will be based on the "real" price.

```
// the HTML that is displayed on the product pages
function my_price_html( $html, $_product ) {
    // if this is a variation we want the variation ID probably?
    $id = isset($_product->variation_id) ? $_product->variation_id : $_product->id;
    $custom_price = get_post_meta( $id, 'custom_price', true );
    $custom_price_html = "<b>$custom_price</b>"; // just an example of HTML
    return $custom_price_html;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_price_html', 'my_price_html', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_sale_price_html', 'my_price_html', 10, 2 );

// the HTML that is displayed on the cart
function my_cart_item_price_html( $html, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    $id = $cart_item['data']->id;
    $custom_price = get_post_meta( $id, 'custom_price', true );
    $custom_price_html = "<b>$custom_price</b>"; // just an example of HTML
    return $custom_price_html;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price_html', 'my_cart_item_price_html', 10, 3 );
```

You will need to implement other filters/actions if you want to actually affect the item price, the above just affects the display. A better option might be to implement an action for `save_post` or `update_post_meta` that updates the WooCommerce product price when the custom field value changes (assuming you are using the codex to update this value).

Comment: My plugin is pick 6 random products, and mark them featured, so the list is changes every day. All products has a custom field with a custom price. It will be the best if I change the regular price to the custom field's value, but how can I restore the original price?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do... put 6 random products on sale per day?